# Trouble with EMC vNXE and Cisco Catalyst Configuration for vSphere 5.5

Tags: cisco, emc

Good afternoon, we have recently purchased

-two Cisco Catalyst 2960-x switches
-two Dell PowerEdge 320R server
-1 EMC vNXE 3300-1 storage device

I'm having a difficult time configuring the networking between all these devices.  The intention is to run two vSphere 5.5 esxi hosts on the two Dell servers.  One switch is going to be used for regular network traffic on a 10.10.x.x subnet and the other switch will be used for iSCSI traffic on a 172.10.x.x subnet.  I've created a diagram of how I have the wiring:

http://www.warrenbullock.me/sites/default/files/images/connection-diagram.png

I'm not sure what I've configured incorrectly but I cannot ping anything from the EMC device that is on the 10.10.x.x network.  I'm not very familiar with Cisco switches but I have used the basic web interface to turn on Cisco switch basic configuration for every port except the 1st.  I've gone ahead and created two iSCSI servers on the EMC device, one for each SP-A and SP-B.  The information I've assigned to them is as follows:

SP-A-Eth2 = 172.10.1.100
SP-A-Eth3 = 172.10.2.100

SP-B-Eth2 = 172.10.1.101
SP-B-Eth3 = 172.10.2.101

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on what I might have wrong... I'm at a stand still....

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to ping the iscsi interfaces from a different subnet.  You could establish a default gateway to enable this, but best practice is to disallow communications from non-iscsi to the iscsi vlans.

Also, be sure to setup the correct VLAN ID's on the cisco switchports, eg)

Regular server traffic = 10.10 subnet = vlan 10 on both switches
iSCSI1 = 172.10.1 = vlan 1721 on switch A
iscsi2 = 172.10.2 = vlan 1722 on switch B

Divide your iscsi connections between the 2 switches, so you maintain the storage network in the event of switch failure.

SPA-e2 >> 172.10.1 subnet/vlan >> connect to switch A
SPA-e3 >> 172.10.2 subnet/vlan >> connect to switch B

SPB-e2 >> 172.10.1 subnet/vlan >> connect to switch A
SPB-e3 >> 172.10.2 subnet/vlan >> connect to switch B

ServerA-iscsi1 >> 10.1 subnet/vlan >> connect to switch A
ServerA-iscsi2 >> 10.2 subnet/vlan >> connect to switch B

With this configuration, you maintain a path to both SPs, even in the event of full switch failure, or a failure of an individual NIC on either the array or server.